# for and if statement with variables

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement, openpyxl

Dears,

I'm on writing a code which trait str, we have as data input :

- **Module list**: it's a list of modules with their position and their value (stocked on Excel file )
  Example :

  ```
          |module|position|value|
          |LL700 |   1    |  1  |
          |LL701 |   2    |  1  |
  ```
- **code str** : Example >> (1X1XX1111211XXXXX1XX1XXXXXX1XX4XX12XXXXXX1X1XXXX1XXX1X11XXXXXX1X1X9XX1XXXXXXXX)

following the example above, We have a value 1 in the first position its means LL700 is included in that's code
this is my try :

```
Modulecode = part[Vin1+1:option1]
Cnum=len(Modulecode) # 

print(Modulecode)#str code which need to trait
modlist=500
i=1
j=1

Vinnumber=part[win1+1:wiv1]

print(Vinnumber)

ss=modullist.cell(1,1).value
print(ss)

for i in range(Cnum):
    for j in range(modlist):
        mul=modullist.cell(j,2).value
        mlist=modullist.cell(j,3).value
        if mul ==i and mlist== Modulecode[i]:
            print('LL700')
```

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Elkassah/Desktop/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Elkassah/Desktop')
1X1XX1111211XXXXX1XX1XXXXXX1XX4XX12XXXXXX1X1XXXX1XXX1X11XXXXXX1X1X9XX1XXXXXXXXX
MA45060
Modul
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elkassah\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Elkassah\Desktop\untitled2.py", line 141, in func
    mm=modullist.cell(j,2).value
  File "C:\Users\Elkassah\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 238, in cell
    raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Elkassah\Desktop\untitled2.py", line 209, in <module>
    window.mainloop()

  File "C:\Users\Elkassah\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1420, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the error `Row or column values must be at least 1` caused by `mm=modullist.cell(j,2).value` tell you about the value of `j` (2 is obviously "at least 1") ? *hint*: `range` starts from 0  (which is indeed not "at least 1") when called with a single argument

Comment: Absolutely yes, but I declared j&i will start with 1 in the code above!

Answer (score 0):

DeepSpace's comment is correct, and it does not matter if you declared variables called 'i' and 'j' and set them to 1 prior to the for-loop. For-loops don't look for previously declared variables to get their value even if there is a previously declared variable which shares the same name; for-loops always start at index = 0.

You can resolve the error two ways:

1. Skip the first iteration of the for-loops by adding an if statement

```
for i in range(Cnum):
    for j in range(modlist):
        if i > 0 and j > 0: 
            do_stuff()
```

This would resolve the error, but based on your code, I don't think you want this option. Option 2 is likely what you need.

2. Use a formula based on the for-loop index values to calculate the row number such that the first iteration is on row 1

```
for i in range(Cnum):
    for j in range(modlist):
        mul=modullist.cell(row=j + 1, column=2).value
        mlist=modullist.cell(row=j + 1, column=3).value
        if mul ==i+1 and mlist== Modulecode[i+1]:
            print('LL700')
```

Option 2 functionally combines your current for-loop code with your declarations that I and j should be equal to 1 prior to the for-loop executing